# Is the sensation of air movement inside a closed cornering car due to differences in air density

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, everyday-life, convection

The scenario.  At ambient temperature of 0degC to -5degC car sets off, engine warms up and heater is turned max temp and high blower on with recirculate feature (faster heating, no cold make-up air or venting) and front of car and foot well warms up nicely.

Sometimes when turning a corner there is a sensation of the air temperature changing either hotter or colder.

I am curious if this is attributable to differences in air density and the angular acceleration causing [thermosiphon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermosiphon) effect or tides in the [inversion layers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(meteorology))?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking about. "Sensations" are subjective and physiological/psychological - eg optical illusions. (Why does the effect only happen "sometimes"?) Even if other people have the same sensations, it is difficult to try to explain them using physical concepts. They need to be something which can be measured using scientific instruments.

Comment: I have felt the same sensation.  It is caused by the air from the vents (which has a different density than the remainder of the mixed air in the cabin) experiencing a horizontal buoyant force as a result of the pseudo-body-force  (horizontal gravity) created by the radial acceleration associated with the cornering.

Comment: Consider a helium balloon in a moving car. When the car brakes which direction will the balloon move?

Comment: @sammygerbil Perhaps the fact that I forgot to put a question mark after my heading got your hackles up before reading the rest of the question.  My sensation may be due to radiated heat or acoustic effects that is causing my sensation but I very much doubt it is due to group hypnosis.  My wife and another commenter have also felt these sensations.  Some people sneeze when they get sunshine up their nose, is this also illusion?

Comment: @JimGarrison Interesting test case, I expect it would move to the back.  I do suspect that it is something that simple and the warm air collected in the foot well or above the dash is pushed to the inside when the denser cold air swings to the outside of the curve, I have never heard it mentioned before anywhere.

Comment: No, I did read your question more than once before commenting. I am being sceptical about something which (you admit) has not been mentioned before. The description in the 1st paragraph suggests forced convection may be dominant, and I don't see how your suggestions in the last paragraph work. Jim Garrison's example does not require movement of whole packets of air, only transmission of pressure. Optical illusions are not hypnosis but alternative conclusions based on the same sensations.  But I accept that your sensations are real; my mention of subjectivity is misplaced, I apologise.

Comment: @KalleMP You are correct. The temporary acceleration creates a pressure gradient front to back and the balloon's buoyancy pushes it towards the lower pressure end (the back).